# Ordering datagridviewcolumn in descending order C#

Tags: c#

I have created a program that has a events feature that will show all upcoming events scheduled. I would like the events to be in descending order. However, the code which I used seems to work well but doesn't order the dates correctly. Would you be able to give me some advice on what altercations can be made, please?

Thanks.

```
dataGridView15.Sort(dataGridView15.Columns["dateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn2"], System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Comment: If the dates are not actually dates, but merely strings, yeah that will happen - numerals are different than numbers.

Comment: If you want to sort date *strings*, as it appears you are doing, then the date format must be something like yyyy-MM-dd, as in 2020-07-08.